# External HDD shows up as two separate HDDs in Disk Utility after executing parted

Tags: external-hdd, disk-utility, parted

Good day to all,

as I mention in my title, the external HDD shows up as two separate HDDs (..kind of) in Disk Utility after executing the following command:

`sudo parted -l`

In particular, once I mount the external HDD, this is what Disk Utility
looks like:
[Disk Utility before executing command parted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5DDx.png)

I also note that I cannot access the smart data on that disk in Disk Utility.

However, after executing the parted command, this is what Disk Utility looks like:
[Disk Utility after executing command parted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRgH2.png)

Now I can also actually see the internal mobile HDD, with its own serial number, and also access its smart data.

Could someone educate me on what explains this behavior?

In any case, this issue does not bother me, the HDD is working fine, it is just a strange issue and I would like to have some explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `gparted`?

Comment: @heynnema yes it does, probably parted pings the HDD somehow.