# RAID0 HDDs show up separately in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I have an all in one XOTIC PC with Windows 10, I installed Ubuntu 16.04. In Windows I can see and access my RAIDed HDDs, but in Ubuntu they show up as two separate disks.

In the BIOS, they are RAID disk with level 0.

here is the result of `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT`:

```
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE          TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      1,8T isw_raid_member disk 
sdc      1,8T isw_raid_member disk 
sda    931,5G                 disk 
├─sda4 466,8G ntfs            part 
├─sda2   100M vfat            part /boot/efi
├─sda5 464,1G ext4            part /
├─sda3    16M                 part 
└─sda1   499M ntfs            part
```

As we see Ubuntu sees them as RAID members, but I am not sure why they are separate! I am completely new to Ubuntu, and I went through [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04#creating-a-raid-0-array)  and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04#creating-a-raid-0-array) but they were not of much help, because I don’t think I should set the RAID up manually. In Ubuntu 17.10, it was recognized without an extra work. I looked into [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896111/external-hdd-shows-up-as-two-separate-hdds-in-disk-utility-after-executing-parte) questions which is similar to mine, but it is not answered yet

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Can you please [edit] your question and remove the screen shot and change it by text as a screenshot is not searchable...  Also: RAID-0 is worse than no RAID at all from a reliability perspective, especially if it's a software RAID. (what this looks like)

Comment: From the manufacturer is set to RAID0 as I see it in the BOIS.

Comment: Yup, so [was my system and I removed it immediately](https://superuser.com/questions/1264858/remove-raid0-and-move-windows-to-ssd-acer-predator-17). It's great for speed, **but it's the worst of the worst for reliability.**  Make *daily*  backups if you want to keep it this way and be prepared to lose 1 day of work in half of the  MTBF of one HD.

Answer (score 4):

What you have on your motherboard is [fake raid](https://skrypuch.com/raid/). This essentially relies on software on the host OS, to support it. ISW is Intel Software Raid.

On Ubuntu this is called dmraid, and can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install dmraid
```

This will install dmraid. Next, ask dmraid to assemble the drives:

```
sudo dmraid -a
```

Now you should be able to see a new device with `sudo lsblk`, which you can mount in the normal way.

Dmraid will run on each boot, and assemble the devices by default, so you can [add the new device to `/etc/fstab` to automatically mount it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup) during boot.

In general, **don't use fakeraid**. Use mdadm on Linux. The load is handled by the CPU anyway, and with mdadm it's standardized and will work on any computer, with or without chipset support.